# Excel 2016 Chart Text Labels

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel 2016 I want to show Labels on a Chart.

I have a function, alph, that has letters to corresponding numbers:A to 1, B to 2, AA to 27, etc.

I have data populated into Sheets("Data") already and the Chart works without the DataLabels.

```
    For s = 1 To 18
        ns = (s - 1) * 2
        Max = "32"
        Sheets("Analysis").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
        Sheets("Analysis").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SeriesCollection(s).XValues = Sheets("Data").Range(alph(ns + 1) & "26:" & alph(ns + 1) & Max)
        Sheets("Analysis").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SeriesCollection(s).Values = Sheets("Data").Range(alph(ns + 2) & "26:" & alph(ns + 2) & Max)
        Sheets("Analysis").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SeriesCollection(s).Name = nameA(s)
        Sheets("Analysis").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SeriesCollection(s).Points(s).DataLabels.HasDataLabel = True
        Sheets("Analysis").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SeriesCollection(s).Points(s).DataLabels.Position = xlLabelPositionBelow
        Sheets("Analysis").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SeriesCollection(s).Points(s).DataLabels.Text = nameA(s)
    Next s
```

Comment: Can you share the rest of your code ? it will be easier to debug ? are you getting an error?

Comment: have you looked at my answer below ?

Answer (score 0):

I am using a Sub that dynamically adds Series to a chart, then it sets the parameters (which are different) for each Series.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateChart()

Dim Cht                                 As ChartObject
Dim Cht_Series                          As Series
Dim Series_Cntr                         As Integer

Set Cht = Worksheets("Analysis").ChartObjects("Chart 1")

With Cht.Chart
    Set Cht_Series = .SeriesCollection(s)
    With Cht_Series
        .XValues = Sheets("Data").Range(alph(ns + 1) & "26:" & alph(ns + 1) & Max)
        .Values = Sheets("Data").Range(alph(ns + 2) & "26:" & alph(ns + 2) & Max)
        .Name = nameA(s)

        .ApplyDataLabels
        With .DataLabels
            .Position = xlLabelPositionBelow

            ' decide what you want to display on the Data labels
            .ShowValue = True
            .ShowSeriesName = True
            .ShowCategoryName = True
        End With
    End With
End With

End Sub
```